# Не работает google reCaptcha v3

Tags: recaptcha, google-recaptcha

Что я делаю не так?

1. [В консоли настройки капчи устанавливаю свой домен.](http://prntscr.com/nftpow)
2. [Копирую ключ для фронта.](http://prntscr.com/nftqtc)
3. [На фронте вставляю код для сайта на страницу
   html.](http://prntscr.com/nftr52)
4. [Результат](http://prntscr.com/nftrfl)

На тестовых ключах на локал хосте все работает и фронт и бек. А вот когда реальный ключ загоняю с реальным доменом и выкладываю сайт на хост. Проблема. Что делать?

Comment: одинарные ковычки в **key** уберите

Comment: Денис Небесный  Тогда вообще капча не отображается...

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то это AngularJS? Если да, то вы не предоставили конфигурацию и подключён ли у вас angular-recaptcha.js?